# Date plots with function "addtodate" in Matlab

Tags: matlab, date, plot

In Matlab, I want to create a plot of the hourly prices "DataSeriesEl" (size is 744 x 1). They should go from January 1, 2008, 00:00:00 to January 31, 2008, 23:00:00. However, my code switches at January 7 to 05:59:59 - see below. Do you know what the problem is?

```
StartYearData = 2008;

StartMonthData = 1;

StartDayData = 1;

date(1) = datenum(StartYearData,StartMonthData,StartDayData,0,0,0);

for m = 2:length(DataSeriesEl)
    date(m) = addtodate(date(m-1), 1, 'hour');
end

str = datestr(date)
```

Comment: I deleted my former answer as it did not seem to answer your question properly. Could you upload your data and link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a much simpler solution if you use this method , for this method you dont have to use a for loop

```
StartYearData = 2008;

StartMonthData = 1;

StartDayData = 1;

EndDayData = 31;
dates(1) = datenum(StartYearData,StartMonthData,StartDayData,0,0,0);
dates(2) = datenum(StartYearData,StartMonthData,EndDayData ,23,0,0);
myDateTime = datetime(dates, 'ConvertFrom', 'datenum')
hours = (myDateTime (2) - myDateTime (1) )/duration(1,0,0);
date = linspace(myDateTime(1),myDateTime(2),hours +1 )
```